# How to properly handle Cross Origin (CORS) for a Spring-based Rest API

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, rest, cors

I am working on an application with a completely decoupled front and back end. The front end has been implemented using Angular and the back end is implemented in Java using Spring extensively. Communication between the two is done via a Spring-managed Rest API. In addition to this, we have an external third party application(s) that also use this Rest API. So the API is used for two purposes: (1) as a "generic" API for an indeterminate number of clients and (2) as a very specific API designed specifically to meet the requirements of the Angular front end. We have separate Controllers to handle the separate concerns.

The problem I ran into was that of CORS. At the moment I have just annotated the Controllers with `@CrossOrigin` and that is fine for now but, I would need a more secure solution before we go live. I am aware that you can specify certain domains to limit when cross origin requests are allowed, however, that would not work for me. It would work if we just had the Angular front end to consider, but what about the external clients? There domains are not known. I almost need some sort of mechanism for the clients to authenticate and register themselves at runtime and then only these registered clients will be allowed to perform Cross Origin requests.

So that is what I am asking: given the above, what is the best solution to my problem? I need a solution that protects against Cross Site Request Forgery as well as meets my requirements stated previously.

Comment: Hi, what about creating a rest controller in your front end app acting as a proxy to your backend services ? basically the front end would call localhost  and the controller would call the remote back end services ?

Comment: @Seb that doesn't really solve my problem, you are focused only on the web front end piece of the question - which is actually the easier part to solve since that domain is known so I cannot register it with a CorsFilter on app startup. Unless you are suggesting that the external clients call the web app and in order to access my back end Rest API - which is definitely not the way to go because you have basically coupled things. If the web front end is down, the back end Rest API should still be accessible. Or maybe I have completely misunderstood your suggestion (??)

Comment: true I was focused on front end. my bad. 
Does external clients needs to access same services (exactly) as your front ?

Comment: @Seb no not exactly the same, there might end up being some overlap but there isn't at the moment

Comment: This looks like the authentication + whitelisting approach you're talking about: https://medium.com/@m.taylor/implementing-secure-cors-apis-b4a5200f69d1